# How to pass username and password to Jedis?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

I am trying to use Redis 6.0 ACL with the Sentinel for High Availability. Currently, only Redis servers are configured with usernames and passwords with the help of the ACL feature and there is no credential configured for Sentinels.

I am using Jedis for interacting with Redis but seems Jedis library does not provide a way to specify the username and password. Please find below the configs

```
#redis-server.conf
bind 172.x.x.x 127.0.0.1
protected-mode no
daemonize yes
logfile "redis-server.log"
pidfile "/var/run/redis.pid"
dir "server"
masterauth "***"
masteruser "replica-user"

aclfile "users.acl"


#redis-sentinel.conf
bind 172.x.x.x 127.0.0.1
protected-mode no
port 26379
daemonize yes
pidfile "/var/run/redis-sentinel.pid"
logfile "redis-sentinel.log"
dir "sentinel"
sentinel myid 682b15dd6d8606dde7e8802a5aebb1c15ab1864e
sentinel deny-scripts-reconfig yes
sentinel monitor rediscluster 172.x.x.x 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds rediscluster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout rediscluster 60000
sentinel auth-pass rediscluster 123456
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
user default on nopass ~* +@all
sentinel auth-user rediscluster sentinel-user
sentinel config-epoch rediscluster 1
sentinel leader-epoch rediscluster 1
sentinel known-replica rediscluster 172.x.x.x 6379
sentinel known-replica rediscluster 172.x.x.x 6379
sentinel known-sentinel rediscluster 172.x.x.x 26379 f2083b5ea2e419fb38c538314f5ed35439ea8572
sentinel known-sentinel rediscluster 172.x.x.x 26379 cc85a1fd3265797c883891609ac5b4e182b9b99a
sentinel current-epoch 1

#users.acl
user default off -@all
user sentinel-user on >123456 +multi +slaveof +ping +exec +subscribe +config|rewrite +role +publish +info +client|setname +client|kill +script|kill
user replica-user on >123456 +psync +replconf +ping
user app-user on >123456 ~* +@all
```

Below is the java code for creating JedisConnectionFactory but I don't find any suitable method for passing the username and password

```
@Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisSentinelConfiguration redisSentinelConfiguration = new RedisSentinelConfiguration();
        redisSentinelConfiguration.setMaster(env.getProperty(Constant.REDIS_MASTER_NAME_KEY));
        redisSentinelConfiguration.setSentinels(getRedisNodes(env.getProperty(Constant.REDIS_HOST_KEY)));

        Integer conTimeOutInSecs = Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(Constant.REDIS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_KEY));
        Integer maxTotalConn = Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(Constant.REDIS_MAX_TOTAL_CONN_KEY));
        Integer minIdleConn = Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(Constant.REDIS_MIN_IDLE_CONN_KEY));
        Integer maxIdleConn = Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(Constant.REDIS_MAX_IDLE_CONN_KEY));

        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxTotalConn);
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(minIdleConn);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxIdleConn);
        JedisClientConfiguration jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder()
                .clientName(env.getProperty(Constant.APPLICATION_NAME_KEY))
                .usePooling().poolConfig(poolConfig).and().connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(conTimeOutInSecs)).build();
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisSentinelConfiguration,
                jedisClientConfiguration);

        return jedisConFactory;
    }
```

Is there any way by which I can pass the username and password when creating the JedisConnectionFactory?

Comment: The issue is resolved by upgrading the spring-data-redis to 2.6.3.

Comment: Can you post a detailed answer? I don't quite follow how your comment resolves the Jedis User/Pass issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code with `jedis:4.0.0.`

```java
redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisClientConfig

DefaultJedisClientConfig defaultJedisClientConfig = DefaultJedisClientConfig.builder().user("vboxredis").password("vboxredis001").build();

Jedis jedis = new Jedis("192.168.56.101",63791,defaultJedisClientConfig);
```

Or use JedisPool:

```java
private static JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool("192.168.56.101",63791,"vboxredis","vboxredis001");
```